# Dagger inject onStart

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, dagger

Research: Couldn't find anything similar.

I have a `Singleton`and I inject it into my `SecondActivity` in the Constructor using `InjectorUtil.inject(this);`. I then call `mySingleton.getPersonCount()` and it gives me the count.

My problem is that when I leave the app and return to it.  From my understanding causing the `onStop()` then `onStart()`.  When it starts it instantly crashes and says that `mySingleton.getPersonCount()` is `null`.

So should I be calling `InjectorUtil.inject(this);` in `onStart()` too? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [fb-android-dagger](https://github.com/adennie/fb-android-dagger) to be useful when setting up dagger in my app. I inject my activities in `onCreate` and have never had to worry about whether or not Android has destroyed them.

I would also refer to [stopping and restarting an activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html). Android calls `onStart` both when it creates your activity and when it restarts the activity from the stopped state, so you do not want to inject there (unless you're re-creating something you released in `onStop`)